# How do you get the file from current project

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, migration

How can I get the script from .sql file located in the same project? I'm trying input this code below:

```
string path = System.IO.Path.Combine(System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location), @"../Scripts/Procedures/GetStudents.sql");
    var sqlContent = File.ReadAllText(path);
    migrationBuilder.Sql(sqlContent);
```

But in results I get communicate:

> Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\Project\api\Web.Students.Api\Pgs.Web.Students.Api\bin\Debug\Scripts\Procedures\GetStudents.sql'.

File name GetStudents.sql located in this path below:

> 'C:\Users\Project\api\Web.Students.DataAccess\Pgs.Web.Students.DataAccess\bin\Debug\Scripts\Procedures\GetStudents.sql'.

Comment: Does the problem still occur if you use `GetEntryAssembly` instead? Returns where the .exe is, not where some .dll is. Note that these methods do not know anything about your solutions and projects, they only know where the compiled assemblies are. This is most likely where your .exe is and not in the project directory of some class library.

Comment: Place the file under the project Resources. And then use it like this: 'MyProject.Properties.Resources.GetStudents.sql'